# how to append circle to svg file?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a separate svg file embedded in html file, I want to add a circle to that svg via javascript. Following is what I have now:

```
var mySvg=document.getElementById("SVGDoc");
var svgDom=mySvg.getSVGDocument();

.....

<object id="SVGDoc" type="image/svg+xml" data="3rdFloorVersion2.svg"></object>
```

but as I know, there is no append() method for this `svgDom` object. Anyone know how to solve this? I know there is a solution that requires to copy the svg content inside the html file, but I want to keep them separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var circle = svgDom.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
circle.setAttribute("r", "10");
// etc for x, y 
svgDom.documentElement.appendChild(circle);
```

Note that you can only call mySvg.getSVGDocument() after the onload event of the `<object>` tag has fired so you need to do something like:

```
<object id="SVGDoc" onload="go()"...></object>

<script>
function go() {
    var mySvg=document.getElementById("SVGDoc");
    var svgDom=mySvg.getSVGDocument();
    ...
}

</script>
```